# Adding columns to a model in a Rails 3 app for a database with the schema dumped from heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, model, dump

In my rails app I have a model `Events`.  It has several columns which were created through following this guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/export-from-heroku-postgres and then performing `rake db:schema:dump`.

Now I want to add some new columns to the `Event` model. I tried editing `schema.rb` and restarting the app but that didn't seem to work.  Anyone know the proper way to proceed?

----Edit-------

Specifically I added this line to the `Event` model in `schema.rb`.

```
t.datetime "date_time"
```

When I click the link to add a event in the rails app I receive this error:

```
undefined method `date_time' for #<Event:0x007fdb59a87118>
```

Comment: "didn't seem to work". Do you mean "appeared to have no effect", "produced the following error message: ...", or something else?

Comment: I'll add some details.  Sorry, it's getting a little late here, not paying enough attention.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `schema.rb` file is a representation of the current state of the database schema, it is *written* by the database migration process, not *read*.

If you want to add a new column, [create a migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration):

```
$ rails generate migration AddNewEventStuff
$ vim db/migrate/add_new_event_stuff*.rb
```

Then add your columns:

```
class AddNewEventStuff < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column ...
  end
end
```

Everything except the `add_column` should be there already. Once you have your migration, do a `rake db:migrate` and you're done. Now you should see some changes in your `schema.rb`.

See the [Ruby on Rails Migration Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for further details and different ways to build your migrations.

Comment: That did it!  You are a wealth of knowledge my friend! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try `heroku run rake db:schema:load`. That said, it's probably the wrong way to go about. Instead, you should make changes to your schema via migrations, and then run a `heroku run rake db:migrate` on it.